# Number of obtuse (or acute) triangles with sides $8$, $15$, and integer $x$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, triangles, triangle-inequality

> Consider obtuse-angled triangles with sides $8$ cm, $15$ cm, and $x$ cm. If $x$ is an integer, then how many such triangles exist?

I approached this problem by assuming three cases :-

- *1st* Case where $x<8<15$ then as per triangle's side rules $x+8 > 15 \Rightarrow x>7$.
- *2nd* Case where $8<x<15$ then as per triangle's side rules $x+8 > 15 \Rightarrow x>7$.
- *3rd* Case where $8<15<x$ then as per triangle's side rules $15+8 > x \Rightarrow x<23$.

So combining all the cases I can say that $7<x<23$ and there could be $15$ possible triangles but the answer given is $10$. What am I doing wrong?

> And also how one can find the number of acute-angled triangles with sides $8$ cm, $15$ cm, and} $x$ cm given the same condition for $x$.

Please help!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Use law of cosine to calculate cosines of each  angle, need to be possitive .

Comment: In an obtuse triangle,  the square of the side opposite the obtuse angle is strictly greater than the sum of the squares of the other two sides. Applying this would eventually rule out the cases not satisfying the condition.

Comment: @DRSKMOBINULHAQUE : And what would that be for an acute triangle? is there any similar rule for acute-angled traingle?

Comment: @Ganit Try not memorize it as a rule. It's simply Pythagoras' theorem. When the angle is acute you should only reverse the inequality sign.

Comment: @Ganit This is an application of the cosine rule. In case of an acute triangle,  the square of any side would be strictly lesser than the sum of the squares of the other two sides, since all the angles are acute.

Comment: dodoturkoz Yes, that helps as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in a triangle, $a \leq b \leq c$, $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ gives you right angled triangle. $a^2 + b^2 \gt c^2$ gives you acute angled triangle and $a^2+b^2 \lt c^2$ gives you obtuse angled triangle (you can see it by law of cosine or using geometry).

When $7 \lt x \leq 15$, $8^2 + x^2 \lt 15^2$ gives you obtuse angled triangles. So you get $7 \lt x \lt 13$.

When $15 \lt x \lt 23$, $8^2 + 15^2 \lt x^2$ gives you obtuse angled triangles. So you get $17 \lt x \lt 23$.

Comment: And also how one can find the number of acute-angled triangles with sides 8cm,15cm and xcm given the same condition for x is given.

Comment: You already found all possibilities. Now once we know obtuse angled triangles, rest are all acute angled or right angled. If it is right angled, you will get $a^2+b^2 = c^2$.

Comment: We see $15^2-8^2$ is not a square number so it is clear no right angled triangle there. Now $15^2+8^2 = 289 = 17^2$ So that is the only right angled triangle. Rest are all acute angled.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Let AC=b=15 , BC=a=8 and AB=c=x we may write . Suppose $\angle ABC=90^o$ then :

$x^2=15^2-8^2\rightarrow x=12.68$

Therefore $ 15-8=7<x<12$, so numbers 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12  can be candidates, that is there is 5 possibility.Now suppose $\angle ACB=90^o$ then:

$AC^2=x^2=15^2+8^2=289\rightarrow x=17$

In this case $17<x<15+8=23$ and numbers 18, 19, 20,21 and 22 can be right for x.Hence total possibility is 10.

For acute triangle we must have $12<x<17$ which gives $x=13, 14, 15, 16$ as four possibility.